# Website Login page doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

okay. I for the life of me cannot figure out why the login page code won't work. maybe i missed something. if you need the full source code i am more than glad to give it. I have it trying to get user name compare it with the list ot find its password then compare to the password in the textbox. then if the passwords match. redirect to account page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
namespace Vanguardian_Tournaments
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void LoginBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string ckUser = "Select Count(*) from UserData where CFAName = '" + LoginTB.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cfaComm = new SqlCommand(ckUser, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cfaComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            conn.Close();
            if (temp == 1)
            {

                conn.Open();
                string ckPass = "Select Password from UserData where CFAName = '" + LoginTB.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand PassComm = new SqlCommand(ckPass, conn);
                string password = PassComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
                conn.Close();
                if (password == LoginPassTB.Text)
                {
                    Session["Login"] = LoginTB.Text;
                    Response.Redirect("Account.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    LoginLbl.Text = "CFA Name or Password is incorrect";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LoginLbl.Text = "CFA Name does not exist";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? Does it explode?

Comment: It doesn't do anything when i put in the user name in password in the login form

Comment: I cannot find a problem in it. and whats a SQL injection Vulnerability

Comment: Does browser call back to server?

Comment: SQL Injection aside, you are also storing passwords as clear text (a no-no). Why not just leverage the ASP.NET authentication? Also you'll still need to clarify `It doesn't do anything`. So I guess it isn't exploding, but what does it do? Not run `LoginBTN_Click`? Not log you in? Typically you'd set an authentication cookie on successful login.

Comment: when i press login button it reloads the page but clears the password

Comment: Im sorry ive never made a website before, and im trying to learn. and ASP.NET authentication? whats that

Comment: Before proceeding, Google "SQL Injection". Then come back to your coding issues.

Comment: I understand what SQL injection is now.. but how does that apply with why this code isn't working. im not trying to create something perfect for now. just something that works. then go back and improve. and i have put breakpoints out but it doesn't break when i press the button. so i assume its not even connecting

Comment: I had the function named wrong. i figured it out. but I would love any links to help me make my code more secure.

Comment: Beau: part of learning is starting to hack away at things before you actually know what you're doing, so keep it up. However, and this is important, don't **ever** use this program as you've currently got it written in any kind of real application. It is not secure in any way. It's totally fine to mess around like this for now, just don't put anything out there into the real world to be used until you've learned about proper password storage and avoiding SQL injection. Here's an article: [Why passwords should be hashed](http://bit.ly/10HL6mJ). See also the article @aditya linked in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you place a breakpoint on the if statement and check the value of temp? it could be that your code is never entering the if block. Also are you using the login control provided by asp.net? If yes, you cannot proceed in this manner you need to follow these steps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178329%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I am not using any login controls by asp.net

Comment: did you check the value being turned for temp by placing a breakpoint there?

Comment: the breakpoint doesn't stop the program. so i assume the program isn't accessing the function for some reason.

Comment: OMG... i had the function named wrong LoginBTN_Click was supposed to be LoginBTN_Click1

Answer (score 2):

Please visit this link. It will give you some idea how a hacker can take information from your login for query
https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/donw/archive/2014/10/06/best-practices-building-secure-web-applications-with-devexpress-part-1.aspx